# How to disable this error badge on NetBeans?

Tags: java, netbeans

[image]

Everething works fine and I need that "Other Sources" there.
But that red badge is annoying!

I looked "Options" for a hint I could disable but I found nothing.

Comment: Get rid of that badge by resolving the error(s)? What do you see when you trace that error badge down into the "Other Sources" folder (and its sub-folders)? Where, specifically, is the error? I'm guessing maybe a HTML file, or CSS file, or JavaScript file in a `resources` folder...?

Comment: I cannot trace it. I'm going to edit my question to include the image with 3 levels open (there are too much levels). The badge doesn't appear.

Comment: Later I removed the resorce and added it again. Now the errors propagate to a hundred of files. Everyone is "Error parsing file". Opening the files, there is no errors. Even if there was, I would not mess with them, because the whole thing is working perfectly. I just want to remove the error badge.

Answer (score 0):

I found that I didn't really need that source. It is already declared as a dependency. So I just removed it. Still learning about Maven, dependencies...